# i want to know device orientation when the view will appear IOS 6

Tags: iphone

I want to know device orientation  when the view will appear.
Previously it was possible using the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method but in IOS 6 it is deprecated.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ) {
        DashBtn.hidden=NO;
    }
    else
    {
        DashBtn.hidden=YES;
        if (self.popoverControllerMain) {
            [self.popoverControllerMain dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        }


    }
    return YES;
}
```

I checked all the  post 
 i.e making rootviewcontroller and

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}// this method is not called

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create category of UINavigationController and add below code                                                     @implementation UINavigationController (Rotation_IOS6)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
  {
  return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
  }

@end

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

instead of

```
(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

refer http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html for details.

Comment: but it wont called when first view loads... i.e without rotating device

Comment: @shyla for that you have to write code in `- (void)viewDidLoad` or `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`

Answer (score 0):

The best option to know the device orientation is

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]
```